# Merge values into single rows grouped by item id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a working SQL query that gets me the values I need like so:

```
SELECT [dev_Inventory].[dbo].[IV00102].[ITEMNMBR],
[dev_Inventory].[dbo].[CCIVtblExtenderData].[WheelName], 
[dev_Inventory].[dbo].[CCIVtblExtenderData].[FinishDesc],
"Qty on Hand" = [dev_Inventory].[dbo].[IV00102].[QTYONHND],
"Qty in Transit" =  
CASE 
   WHEN [dev_Inventory].[dbo].[IV00102].[LOCNCODE] LIKE 'IT-%'  THEN [dev_Inventory].[dbo].[IV00102].[QTYONHND]
   ELSE 0
END,
"Qty in Production" = [dev_Inventory].[dbo].[IV00102].[QTYONORD]
FROM [dev_Inventory].[dbo].[CCIVtblExtenderData]
INNER JOIN [dev_Inventory].[dbo].[IV00102] ON [dev_Inventory].[dbo].[CCIVtblExtenderData].[VendPartNmbr] = [ITEMNMBR];
```

The issue I am having is that I have a lot of duplicates with the same itemnumber and I would like to merge those values along with the quantities as well.

Here is an example of the output that I need to fix:
[image]

So in this scenario this should output a single row:

```
1780CHS105127G71 - CHASE - Brushed Gunmetal - 32 - 0 - 0
```

I realize this may be a fairly simple sql query fix for some and I know I need to sum the QTY fields, but any suggestions on a clean approach using the existing query would be much appreciated

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `SUM()`.

Comment: can you add a query on top of your query like this `SELECT item_num..., sum(qty_in_hand),sum(qty_in_transit),sum(qty_in_prod) FROM ( your_query) group by item_num....`

Comment: Clean approach = use table aliases, and don't use spaces in column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on a clean approach:

```
SELECT 
    i.ITEMNMBR,
    c.WheelName, 
    c.FinishDesc,
    SUM(i.QTYONHND) as QtyOnHand,
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.LOCNCODE LIKE 'IT-%'  THEN i.QTYONHND END) as QtyInTransit,
    SUM(i.QTYONORD) as QtyInProduction 
FROM 
    dev_Inventory.dbo.CCIVtblExtenderData c
    INNER JOIN dev_Inventory.dbo.IV00102 i ON c.VendPartNmbr = i.ITEMNMBR
GROUP BY 
    i.ITEMNMBR,
    c.WheelName, 
    c.FinishDesc
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly thank you. I was getting to this step but was erroring out because I wasn't including wheelname and description in the group by

Comment: Some databases will let you omit columns from the groupby if the db can successfully work out that they are functionally dependent on the columns that are grouped (ie there is no pair of rows where the columns that are grouped have a same value and the non grouped columns have a different values). Sql server is not one of those databases